# Display nav list of content is available with php

Tags: php

I've got this PHP code:

```
<div class="connect_wrap <?php echo $this->class; ?> block" <?php echo $this->cssID; ?>>
<?php if(!$this->empty): ?>
    <?php foreach($this->entries as $entry): ?>
        <div class="entry block <?php echo $entry->class; ?>">
            <div class="tab">

                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="Kunden">Kunden</li>
                    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="Loesungen">Lösungen</li>

                </ul>
                <?php
                $this->import('Database');
                $pName = $entry->field('name')->value();
                $result = \Database::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE partner=?")->execute($pName);
                ?>
                <?php if($result->numRows):?>
                    <div id="Kunden"  class="tab-content current">

                        <?php while($result->next()) { ?>
                            <div class="items">
                                <a href="{{env::url}}/kunden-detail/<?php echo $result->alias; ?>">
                                    <div class="logo">
                                        <img src="<?php $objFile = \FilesModel::findByUuid($result->logo); echo $objFile->path;?>"width="180" height="135">
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>

                <?php
                $this->import('Database');
                $pName = $entry->field('name')->value();
                $result = \Database::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM solutions WHERE solution_provider=?")->execute($pName);
                ?>
                <?php if($result->numRows):?>
                    <div id="Loesungen"  class="tab-content">

                        <?php while($result->next()) { ?>
                            <div class="items">
                                <a href="{{env::url}}/synaptic-commerce-solution/<?php echo $result->alias; ?>">
                                    <div class="logo">
                                        <img src="<?php $objFile = \FilesModel::findByUuid($result->logo); echo $objFile->path;?>"width="180" height="135">
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div>

        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

In that code, I've got two DB queries. My problem is, if there is no data for both queries, the div with the class "connect_wrap" should not be displayed.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the query execution up or preferably: not within the html but in a different file/class. Then add a check before the `content_wrap` div: `if($kundenResult->num_rows >= 1 || $solutionsResult->num_rows >= 1)`. If you just keep the individual checks like you already have, it will only show the `content_wrap` div if either or both of the queries return rows of data.

Comment: Yes, just wrap that if around the content_wrap div

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that is wrong with your code. Try turning on error reporting and display errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1)` before your other code.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to check if the query has data in it and its not empty ? if so try `num_rows` it will return the number of rows that the query found/affected for example to check if th query returned one or more rows

```
if($result->num_rows >= 1) {
//do stuf
} else {
// no result found
}
```

Comment: Does that work, even if the query is inside the if statemant?

Comment: i think you wrote the wrong function `if($result->numRows):` should be `if($result->num_rows >= 1) {`

Comment: This statement is frome the CMS Wiki and it works. What I need, is a if statement that checks if data exists and if not so, it puts nothing out.

Comment: you want to check if data exists in the sql query ?

Comment: Yes, in both queries.

Comment: then my answer should work just pass the mysql query result and it will check if the affected rows are more than one